# Exclude a node based on element - xpath

Tags: xpath, filter

I am importing products into an online store from an XML document. There is the option to filter using xpath.

I would like to exclude certain products based on brand.

I have:

```
<PRODUCT ITEM="12797">
 <BRAND>Boxer Games</BRAND>
 <INCATNAME>Hen And Stag Nights</INCATNAME>
</PRODUCT>

<PRODUCT ITEM="12798">
 <BRAND>Silly Games</BRAND>
 <INCATNAME>Hen And Stag Nights</INCATNAME>
</PRODUCT>
```

I understand I can use  "/product[brand=silly games]" to select the node, but how can I then skip/ignore it?

Comment: You could've come up with [something like that of har07](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23493298/1816580).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this way :

```
//PRODUCT[BRAND != 'Silly Games']
```